# Dotnet 6 high memory usage

Tags: asp.net, .net, memory, memory-leaks

Can you confirm that my application just aggressively reserves memory?

App is simple dotnet 6 asp.net (kestrel, server mode). Application gets data from DB (all rows from one table) via EF Core and returns it. Windows 11 x64, 32GB RAM.
I'm just doing stress test and every next test app uses very different amount of memory. From 200 mb to 650mb. Test is always the same.

Every profiler shows a lot of unmanaged memory and can't give me some more accurate info.
Here what I have in VMMap
[image: VMMap]

So two groups from Private Data committed 414 MB when whole app takes 488MB

My thoughts: App aggressively reserves memory because system has a lot (32GB) and don't release it because OS doesn't need it. Is it true or my app has unmanaged memory leak?

Update:
Also I see this one:

[image]
[image]

Heap grows at the expense of unmanaged memory (I forced GC to show you that) instead of allocate new

Comment: Does your app continues to reserve more and more memory or gets to some limit and stops?

Comment: @virouz98 it stops at a random number(400-600mb). If I continue test sometimes apps can drop\release about 100-200 mb

Comment: So your app does release the memory? If you will for example send requests over and over your app peak usage is 400-600 mb and never more?

Comment: this very rarely happens. For the most part, it grows to a certain point and that's it. But a 50% difference is a very big difference. If each test had a 5% difference in memory usage, then ok, but not 50%. As I say - the test is always the same - for 5 seconds every second I send 1000 requests.

Comment: 32gb isn't a lot. And Windows does swap in disk. Think that the system considers you have a lot of memory is illogical.

Comment: If it does release the memory, then it's not memory leak. Your app consumes a lot of memory, but doesn't have any memory leak imo.